# How to I add Entries to a CalendarFX MonthPage?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, calendar

I'm using the MonthPage from the CalendarFX framework and have problems adding the Entries to the MonthPage. The code below shows the way I'm adding the entries which doesn't throws an exception, but it isn't showing the entries in the User Interface.

```js
public void initCalendar() {
       
        for(Task task : allTasks){
            Entry entry = new Entry(task.getTitle());
            //converting the date to localDate
            Date date = task.getDeadline();
            LocalDate entryDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
            x.changeEndDate(entryDate);
            calendar.addEntry(x);
        }

        CalendarSource calendarSourceTasks = new CalendarSource("Tasks");
        calendarSourceTasks.getCalendars().addAll(calendar);
    
 //Calender and MonthPage is initialized above this method 
 monthPage.getCalendarSources().setAll(calendarSourceTasks);
        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a bit late for answering but maybe it will help others.

For my case I user **DetailledDayView** and **MonthView** and I used this code:

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar("Test");
CalendarSource calendarSource = new CalendarSource("source");
DetailedDayView detailledDayView;

Entry<String> entry = new Entry<>("Hello");
        entry.setInterval(LocalDate.now());
        entry.changeStartDate(LocalDate.now());
        entry.changeEndDate(LocalDate.now());
        entry.changeStartTime(LocalTime.of(12,30));
        entry.changeEndTime(LocalTime.of(13,30));
        calendar.addEntry(entry);

// You do the adding here and the entry will be displayed automatically
calendarSource.getCalendars().addAll(calendar);
detailledDayView.getCalendarSources().setAll(calendarSource);
```

Since you are using **MonthPage** and not **MonthView** you have to change the last line to:

```
monthPage.getMonthView.getCalendarSources().setAll(calendarSourceTasks);
```

I hope my solution helped someone!
Nice coding :)